# apending list using re library and print list python

Tags: python, loops

I'm trying to append content into a list using re for searching and i am not able to print the appended list:

```
ulat = []
lat = open("output1.txt", "r").read()
def myfn2():    
    for lin in lat:
        if re.match("(.*)(L|l)at(.*)", lin):
            print (lin.replace(" ", "")),
        ulat.append(str(lin.replace(" ", ""))),
        print(ulat),
myfn2()
```

Terminal output just says "None"

Comment: Can you provide a minimum example of what's in `output1.txt`?

Comment: u'percentage_match_in_topic': 0.0,
               u'percentage_match_with_op': 0,
               u'post_activity': None,
               u'post_id': 1904364,
               u'preview_height': 0,
               u'preview_image': u'',
               u'preview_link': u'',
               u'preview_source': u'',
               u'preview_source_icon': u'',
               u'preview_title': u'',
               u'preview_width': 0,
               u'privacy': u'ALL',
               u'share': 0,

Comment: put this in question, not in comment - it will be more readable.

Comment: use `print(lin)` to see what you have. You read all into one string using `read()` and then `for` get char, not line of text.

Comment: im trying but i dont know how this works :(

Comment: if you don't know how it works then use `print()` in many places to display values in variables and some usefull information (ie. "I am in for loop") and you will see how it works. OR learn how to use debuger.

Comment: i tried print(lin) and no output

Comment: where did you use it ? in loop, directly after `for`? Then check `print(lat)` maybe you have empty string.

Comment: Please put your `output1.txt` content in the question and use formatting to format it

Comment: as I said before - you main mistake can be `read()` - you need `readlines()`

Answer (score 0):

Are you executing this code in an interactive shell?
If yes, "None" is probably the result of the function you are calling: myfn2

most likely you are not reading from the correct file or the file is simply empty causing the for loop not to be executed.

Answer (score 0):

its working now without making it a function

```
`ulat = []
lat = open("output1.txt", "r")  
for lin in lat:
    if re.match("(.*)(L|l)at(.*)", lin):
            print (lin.replace(" ", "")),
        ulat.append(str(lin.replace(" ", ""))),
        print(ulat),
```

but its appending same line may times 
any solution for that ?